# How do I install the Infinity Headset drivers in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers

I've recently purchased an Infinity Headset (bluetooth), but my PC doesn't recognise it.
Does it need some specific drivers?

Comment: Check out http://www.bluesoleil.com/ - "BlueSoleil 10 is one of the most popular professional Windows-based Bluetooth applications, developed by IVT with great innovation and independence. Bluesoleil is able to fulfill demands of integrating a diverse array of Bluetooth enabled digital devices, such as mobile phones, headsets, printers, keyboards and so on. You can also establish networks and exchange data with other Bluetooth enabled computers."

Comment: @Braiam That rather depends on whether the software sets up a virtual interface.

Comment: Can you see any unknown devices in the Device Manager?